# How do I get a rounder body?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

The people of Shiveria won't let me race until I get a rounder body. I found the racer who doesn't want to race, and he said anyone can take his place, but everyone says I am too small! How do I get a rounder body so I can race for the multi moon prize?

Comment: He needs a hat. Maybe you can share yours?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Like many other entities in the game, you can possess the racer who doesn't want to participate. This will let you enter the race.

Comment: I didn't think of that, because I tried hitting other Shiveria residents and the hat didn't work on them, so I just mistakenly assumed it would be the same for that guy.

Comment: Make sure to pay attention to which NPCs are wearing hats and which aren't

Comment: @Ronan I didn't even think of that! I will pay more attention to that detail.

Comment: Note that there is a minor bug here. The racer cannot be possessed until you've talked to them. I talked to them, ran back, ran back through the door (loading screen), and could not possess them until I talked to them again.